# Why does select-word-style stop me from using backward-kill-word for leading whitespace?

Tags: zsh, line-editor, zle

If I have just some whitespace at be beginning of my zsh prompt, I can usually `^W` (`backward-kill-word`) it away. However, as soon as I load `select-word-style` - even if I don't select any special style - this doesn't work anymore. When I `select-word-style shell` it works again, but that's not the style I want by default...

Is there a way to avoid this annoying behavior? Of course I could create a custom widget which removes the whitespace if necessary and otherwise calls `backward-kill-word`, but that feels like a pretty dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

`select-word-style` unfortunately has many cases for which it does not work well, no matter how you configure it. Even less fortunately, Zsh default word editing widgets don't really do a great job either. To address this, I created a [plugin called `zsh-edit`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit/blob/main/README.md#better-backwardforward-kill-word-widgets-with-subword-matching) that includes kill/move word widgets that work in a more sensible way. I encourage you to try it out.